# regex for html tags in pom xml using maven-replacer-plugin

Tags: regex, maven, maven-2, pom.xml

I am trying to find and replace an html tag with pom.xml using maven-replacer-plugin.
With the current configurations, I am getting an error that "Missing end tag address" it means pom is not escaping open tag `<` and close tag `>`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <executions>      
        <execution>
        <id>replace-script-reset-path-variable</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>replace</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
            <include>${basedir}/books/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <replacements>
                <replacement>
                    <token>/<(address)>/</token>
                    <value>/<(address)>//abc.com</value>
                </replacement>
            </replacements>                     
        </configuration>
        </execution>                        
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The aim is to replace all lines in source file which has html tag `<address>` with `<address>abc.com/`

Here is the sample of my source file:

```
<address>books/category/ebooks1/index.html</address>
<address>books/category/ebooks2/index.html</address>
<address>books/category/ebooks3/index.html</address>
<address>books/category/ebooks4/index.html</address>
<address>books/category/ebooks5/index.html</address>
```

After applying regex, the expected source file should be:

```
<address>abc.com/books/category/ebooks1/index.html</address>
<address>abc.com/books/category/ebooks2/index.html</address>
<address>abc.com/books/category/ebooks3/index.html</address>
<address>abc.com/books/category/ebooks4/index.html</address>
<address>abc.com/books/category/ebooks5/index.html</address>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `<` in the actual POM file as `&lt;`, and similarly for `<`,

Comment: i tried this format `&lt;address&gt;` but somehow not working.

Comment: Any reason for the `(` and `)` ?

Comment: you mean this format : (\&lt;)address(\&gt;) , I tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use token and value files. In them you can simply write just this:

```
<address>
```

and

```
<address>abc.com
```

And then you just enter correct path to the file. E.g.:

```
<tokenFile>resources/common/address-token.txt</tokenFile>
<valueFile>resources/common/address-value.txt</valueFile>
```

For more details please refer to [Replacer usage guide](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wiki/UsageGuide)